# Make UIPageControl stop on every page

Tags: ios, xcode, uiwebview, uiscrollview, uipagecontrol

I have 3 pages which all contain youtube videos (webviews) these webviews are inside a scroll view. I used a tutorial to do this, in that tutorial every time you swiped to either direction it would stop at the next page (like in the ios home screen) however mine just keeps moving and then stops depending on how long the swipe motion is.

Here's my code in the .m:

```
#import "FeaturedVideosViewController.h"

@interface FeaturedVideosViewController ()

@end

@implementation FeaturedVideosViewController

@synthesize scrollView, pageControl;

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
if (self) {
    // Custom initialization
}
return self;
}



- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];

pageControlBeingUsed = NO;
{
    CGRect frame;
    frame.origin.x = self.scrollView.frame.size.width * 3;
    frame.origin.y = 0;
    frame.size = self.scrollView.frame.size;

    UIView *subview = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
        [self.scrollView addSubview:subview];

}

self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.scrollView.frame.size.width * 3, self.scrollView.frame.size.height);

self.pageControl.currentPage = 0;
self.pageControl.numberOfPages = 3;
[WebView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.youtube.com/embed/wYkIhYtN7yA"]]];
[WebView2 loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.youtube.com/embed/4O7kTOTg1UE"]]];
[WebView3 loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.youtube.com/embed/vmUW41m93oY"]]];
}

- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)sender {
if (!pageControlBeingUsed) {
    // Switch the indicator when more than 50% of the previous/next page is visible
    CGFloat pageWidth = self.scrollView.frame.size.width;
    int page = floor((self.scrollView.contentOffset.x - pageWidth / 2) / pageWidth) + 1;
    self.pageControl.currentPage = page;
}
}

- (void)scrollViewWillBeginDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
pageControlBeingUsed = NO;
}

- (void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
pageControlBeingUsed = NO;
}

- (IBAction)changePage {
// Update the scroll view to the appropriate page
CGRect frame;
frame.origin.x = self.scrollView.frame.size.width * self.pageControl.currentPage;
frame.origin.y = 0;
frame.size = self.scrollView.frame.size;
[self.scrollView scrollRectToVisible:frame animated:YES];

// Keep track of when scrolls happen in response to the page control
// value changing. If we don't do this, a noticeable "flashing" occurs
// as the the scroll delegate will temporarily switch back the page
// number.
pageControlBeingUsed = YES;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
// Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

// Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

- (void)viewDidUnload {
// Release any retained subviews of the main view.
// e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
self.scrollView = nil;
self.pageControl = nil;
}




@end
```

How will i make it stop on each page like the ios home screen for example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you set the [pagingEnabled](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIScrollView_Class/Reference/UIScrollView.html) of the UIScrollView to YES.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // EXISTING CODE
    self.scrollView.pagingEnabled = YES;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Click on UIScrollView then on right side (Attribute Inspector) tick Paging Enabled.
OR
You can set it programaticaly also

```
scrollView.pagingEnabled = yes;
```

That's it...